# NTILE for Sqlite from Pandas gives OPERATIONAL ERROR

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I'm trying to use the NTILE function for querying a SQLite database from pandas, but I haven't succeeded, even though I've rechecked the syntax many times.

Self-contained example below.
Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')

marks = pd.DataFrame({'StudentID': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'],
                      'Marks': [75, 83, 91, 83, 93]})
marks.to_sql('marks_sql', disk_engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Now try to use NTILE:

```
q = """select StudentID, Marks, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC)
        AS groupexample FROM marks_sql"""
pd.read_sql_query(q, disk_engine)
```

The traceback is long, but it's main parts are:

```
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: 'select StudentID, Marks, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC)\n        AS groupexample FROM marks_sql']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `NTILE () OVER` functionality in SQLITE

Gives me the same error, need to create this using more complex query or functions

[Here is a list of unsupported analytical functions](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions) not available in SQLITE

NTILE is one of these

The optimizer goes inside the query first to find `OVER`, which it thinks is a column name and does *not* expect `(` to follow a column name, so gives you this error.

To replicate NTILE try this:

```
select * ,
case 
  when 
    (select count(*)+0.0 from marks_sql b where table.Marks >= b.Marks)
    /(select count(*) from marks_sql ) >0.5 
  then 1 
  else 2 end
from marks_sql;
```

In order to do this in such a way that the table can grow in size and this technique still applies we have do a few things:

So first we order the table by `Marks` (essentially create a ranking).  This counts the rows with higher or equal `Marks`:

```
select count(*)+0.0 from marks_sql b where table.Marks >= b.Marks  --rank of Mark
```

We add `0.0` to make this number a float so our fraction works in the next step.

We then take the rank and divide it by the total row count

```
select count(*) from marks_sql -- row count
```

This gives us a distribution over the range of scores, the percentile for each Student.  But we do not care about each exact percentile, we care about the `NTILE(2)` or whether they are in the top half.

That is where the `CASE` statement comes into play.  If the percentile of the student is over 50% they fall in the #1 group, the top 50th percentile.  Everyone else falls in the #2 group.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thanks! Do you have a reference on how to define NTILE for sqlite? That would be helpful for the answer, I think

Comment: @cd98 took me a minute to replicate, EDIT made with your alternative to NTILE()!

Comment: NTILE ... OVER is now possible in SQLite.

Answer (score 4):

[Window functions](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) are supported in SQLite since version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15). `ntile(N)` is one of the supported window functions:

> Argument N is handled as an integer. This function divides the partition into N groups as evenly as possible and assigns an integer between 1 and N to each group, in the order defined by the ORDER BY clause, or in arbitrary order otherwise. If necessary, larger groups occur first. This function returns the integer value assigned to the group that the current row is a part of.

You can test the version of `libsqlite3` your Python is linked with by:

```
python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
```

For instance:

- Ubuntu Xenial

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:xenial
  # apt update 
  # apt install -y python3
  # python3 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
  3.11.0
  ```
- Official Python Docker image on Debian Buster

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it python:3.6-buster \
      python3 -c 'import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)'
  3.27.2
  ```

And you query works just fine on a SQLite version with window function support:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import pandas
>>> 
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> marks = pandas.DataFrame({
...     'StudentID': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'],
...     'Marks': [75, 83, 91, 83, 93]
... })
>>> marks.to_sql('marks_sql', conn, if_exists='replace')
>>> 
>>> sql = '''
...     SELECT StudentID, Marks, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) g
...     FROM marks_sql
... '''
>>> pandas.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
  StudentID  Marks  g
0        S5     93  1
1        S3     91  1
2        S2     83  1
3        S4     83  2
4        S1     75  2
```